# Use a supertype of an enum as a protocol or generic in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

I'm writing a class that I'd like be able to work with a "generic int enum", with the conditions that the enum in question provides one or more given definitions.

If I write 'pseudo-swift' to demonstrate what I mean (which doesn't compile!), it looks like:

```
protocol enum ConformingEnumSupertype: Int {
    case a_required_case = 1,
    case another_required_case
}

enum ConformingEnum: Int, ConformingEnumSupertype {
    case a_required_case = 1,
    case another_required_case,
    case some_random_case
}

class ClassThatUsesConformingEnum {
    let myEnumValue: ConformingEnumSupertype

    init(aConformingEnumValue: ConformingEnumSupertype) {
         myEnumValue = aConformingEnumValue
    }

    func compareSomething(someEnumValue: ConformingEnumSupertype) {
         if someEnumValue == myEnumValue { 
              // ...etc...
         }
    }
}
```

I'm afraid don't have any compiling sample code for an attempt to put here, because nothing I write that looks like it might work compiles. I've tried using protocol associated types and typealiases, but I've not managed yet.

Comment: Enums don't work like that. What would you expect `aConformingEnumValue` parameter value to be if you passed in a value `ConformingEnum.some_random_case`? Enum is a type that can hold a well-defined set of values. A subset of these values means it's a completely different type.

Comment: The idea that is apart from the common values in ConformingEnumSupertype, my code wouldn't even care about the exact values in the passed-in ConformingEnum, since it only relies on equality checks being available between members of ConformingEnum that it might store. My code won't be switching on exact values of someEnumValue: ConformingEnumSupertype passed in. It will just compare to other instances of same, equal or not equal.

Comment: So to explain the thinking: if you have a var declared as type A, which is in fact an instance of B which subclasses A, and you call a method on that var declared as type A, which is overridden in B, the overriden method *does* get called. The calling code knows nothing about B though. So something being subtype is not something you necessarily need to know about, but can have an effect.

Comment: But yes, I take your point. Your example shows a huge problem with this. The compiler can't be expected to know I won't check the value passed in.